# Помогите Обучение нейросети

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

что я делаю не так? почему на графике и на тестовых данных непонятно что?(только начал проходить ,не судите строго) [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)